# play vidoes in youtube player in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, youtube

I wrote the code as follows to play the videos in youtube embedded player . 
 It opens the player window and shows the vidoe , but does not play .

```
if(self.isYouTube)
    {
        NSString *embedHTML;
        NSComparisonResult order = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion compare: @"4.3" options: NSNumericSearch];
        if (order == NSOrderedSame || order == NSOrderedDescending) {

            embedHTML = @"<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">body {background-color:black; color:black; margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto;}</style></head><body style=\"margin:0\"><embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" airplay=\"allow\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" position=\"fixed\" allowfullscreen=\"true\" autoplay=\"1\" width=\"320.0\" height=\"460.0\"></embed></body></html>";

        } else {

            embedHTML = @"<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">body {background-color:black; color:black; margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto;}</style></head><body style=\"margin:0\"><embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\"  type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" position=\"fixed\" allowfullscreen=\"true\" autoplay=\"1\" width=\"320.0\" height=\"460.0\"></embed></body></html>";

        }


        NSString *contentHtml = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML,self.url];

        [self.webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

        [self.webView loadHTMLString:contentHtml baseURL:nil];

        }
    else 
    {
        NSURL *urlForOpenFile=[NSURL URLWithString:self.url];
        NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlForOpenFile];
        [self.webView loadRequest:request];
    }
```

can u tell me , what's the problem in the code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

iOS doesn't support flash, you should use the HTML 5's new tag `video` to wrap the video url like this:

`<video src="point/to/mov"></video>`

Comment: Thats not true, you can still play the embedded content from youtube in the youtube player. iOs doesnt support flash is true though.

Comment: anyways..it's not playing in the simulator and device also

Comment: Make sure your video url is playable on iOS, that say, mov or mp4 format, not flv.

Comment: @xan what does your answer make change in the Embedded code ?         i am having the some problem in playing youtube video (some video are playing and some of them are not)